# Connect to PostgreSQL in Cpanel with php

Tags: php, postgresql, cpanel

I'm new in this cpanel and I want to ask how to connect to Postgres in cpanel using php?

I use this simple code

```
<?php

$dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test user=domain_test password=test")
or die('connection failed: ' . pg_last_error());

?>
```

and It keep on returning `connection failed` on my browser,
can somebody tell me how to do it correctly?

Comment: And what's the error? (see how to get it here - http://www.php.net/manual/en/pgsql.examples-basic.php)

Comment: the `. pg_last_error()` contains nothing... its empty.. sorry.. i will include it right away...

Comment: Check the php and/or Postgres' logs.

Comment: i have checked the php logs, and did not find anything... regarding to postgres log, i didn't find the file in my cpanel...

Comment: @Diom Look on the file system - it's usually in /var/lib/postgresql or /var/lib/pgsql, but if you're on the kind of hosting system that has CPanel, anything goes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really catch connection errors with `pg_last_error`. You will need to use `pg_connection_status` for that. But it will not give you enough info to take care of the connection issue.

It looks like error reporting is disabled in your case. So give this a try

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

$dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test user=domain_test password=test");

$stat = pg_connection_status($dbconn);
if ($stat === PGSQL_CONNECTION_OK) {
    echo 'Connection status ok';
} else {
    echo 'Connection status bad';
}
```

Comment: Alright I got it, I just need to change the host to host=127.0.0.1